# Adding registry values to all users on domain

Tags: windows, networking, group-policy

I have four registry values I would like to add to both HKCU and HKLM for all  users connected to a network domain. Currently we are manually running a batch file on each of the computers when necessary.

Is there any way I can do this one time and get it over with? I have full permissions over the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a new Registry preference item

1. Open the Group Policy Management Console . Right-click the Group Policy object (GPO) that should contain the new preference item, and then click Edit
2. In the console tree under Computer Configuration or User Configuration , expand the Preferences folder, and then expand the Windows Settings folder
3. Right-click the Registry node, point to New , and select Registry Item .
4. In the New Registry Item dialog box, select an Action for Group Policy to perform.
5. Enter registry settings for Group Policy to configure or remove.
6. Click the Common tab, configure any options, and then type your comments in the Description box.
7. Click OK . The new preference item appears in the details pane.

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc753092.aspx

As previously mentioned, for these settings to work on Windows XP or Server 2003, client side extensions will need to be installed

Answer (score 0):

GPO Preference is what you look for.

Comment: I'd gladly +1 your answer, as it is correct, but it could be so much better if you would edit it to include an [even rudimentary] example. I think that would greatly benefit the OP and future visitors.

Comment: Also keep in mind that this won't work on XP/2003 computers *unless* they've had the client-side extensions patch installed.

Comment: How do I implement a registry value as a GPO preference?

Comment: @RyanRies even on win xp and prior platforms, there is place in GPO to enforce registry, just not as flexible as preference. As a matter of fact, if you don't want to give user ability to later remove that registry, the other setting is better than preference. Not to mention there is CSE you can install on xp to support preference.

Comment: @jscott Thank you very much for giving me credit. - As for your comment, I am a strong believer of self learning, which is a fancy word for "googling". I am also a strong believer that answers to forum question should really only serve as pointers instead of step-by-step guide.

Comment: @strongline Whilst an admirable belief you may believe hold, perhaps you would be interested in [StackExchange's opinion on the subject](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). *"answers to forum question should really only serve as pointers"* is not the spirit of SE answers.